# Django new application working in dev but not in production (Apache server)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a django website working properly in production and dev, recently I downloaded django-tables2 and worked a bit with it with no problem in development on a local server.

However when putting it on my production server it gives me error 500 when going to the url.

I installed it by doing `sudo pip install django-tables2`

Here's the **error log of apache** :

```
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.633848 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400] mod_wsgi (pid=27589): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/coding_platform/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.633932 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400] mod_wsgi (pid=27589): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/coding_platform/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637556 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637611 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/coding_platform/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637618 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637627 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637631 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637639 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637643 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637650 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637655 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637661 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637674 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]     module = import_module(entry)
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637682 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/ENV/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637686 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637692 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637699 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637705 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.637725 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662681429760] [remote 213.152.28.84:63400] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_tables2'
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879245 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397] mod_wsgi (pid=27589): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/coding_platform/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879301 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397] mod_wsgi (pid=27589): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/coding_platform/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879439 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879479 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/coding_platform/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879485 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879492 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879497 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879503 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879507 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879514 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397]   File "/home/ubuntu/coding-platform/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879518 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Tue Nov 27 10:32:39.879535 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 27589:tid 139662563825408] [remote 213.152.28.84:41397] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Here's my **INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'coding',
    'django_tables2',
]
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'coding_platform.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The problem seems to come from wsgi.py but I never modified this file, I made a lot of research but didn't find what is wrong, my guess is that there's an extra step to do for production when downloading extra django packages but it wasnt mentionned anywhere I read sadly.

Comment: It's telling you that you don't have anything called django_tables2. Did you install it? How?

Comment: I installed it with sudo pip install django-tables2

Comment: Did you do that on the production server?

Comment: Yeah I did that for both development and production.

Comment: Your traceback seems to show that you are running in a virtualenv. So you shouldn't be installing things via `sudo`, you should be activating the virtualenv and installing directly with pip there.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, it's working !

Comment: Hehe, apparently the mobile version of the site isn't showing comments... my answer seems redundant upon review of the timestamps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key line in your traceback is this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_tables2'
```

Your new package isn't installed in your production virtualenv. Good luck!